# How to initalize a array of string from a file data

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to print the same data which is in the file.
I have written this code. I am not getting the preferred data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[12][10];

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        fscanf(file, "%s", &name[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", name[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
011073054
10
10
10
3.8 
Badol
011074509 
10
10
10
4.0
```

In my text file I have these lines:

```
Alman
011073054
10 20 28 37
10 18 30 35
10 15 18 34
3.8
Badol
011074509
10 15 18 34
10 20 28 37
10 18 30 35
4.0
```

I am trying to store the lines in an array of strings. Then I want to print the string from that string array. But I don't know why the first line of the text file is not getting assigned in my string array. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you reading each line with `fgets()` followed by `fscanf` to get the first token in the next line?

Comment: If you remove the `fscanf` line, you might get what you want but your arrays are small. `char name[...][10];` cannot hold 11 characters plus a newline plus a null terminator.

Comment: so, how should I store the lines of my file to my string?

Comment: `char name[12][20]; ... while (i < 12 && fgets(name[i], sizeof name[i], file) != NULL) { i++; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems in your code:

- `fscanf(file, "%s", &name[i]);` reads the next word from the file, not from the line just read by `fgets()`. Furthermore `&name[i]` does not have type `char *` that `%s` expects. You should write `fscanf(line, "%s", name[i]);`.
- `fscanf(line, "%s", name[i]);` would only copy the first word on the line, and only if there is a non white space character on the line, leaving `name[i]` uninitialized on blank lines.
- `fscanf(line, "%s", name[i]);` would cause undefined behavior if the word is longer than 11 bytes. Using `fscanf(line, "%11s", name[i]);` would fix this issue.
- note that you need 12 bytes to store `10 20 28 37` as a C string: 11 characters plus a null terminator.

To store the lines, you should just copy the line contents, after check for potential buffer overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[12][12];
    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[100];
        int i, n;
        for (n = 0; n < 12 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), file); n++) {
            size_t len = strcspn(line, "\n");
            if (len >= sizeof(name[n])
                len = sizeof(name[n]) - 1;
            memcpy(name[n], line, len);
            name[n][len] = '\0';
        }
        fclose(file);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", name[n]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to store longer lines, you should use an array of `char *` and duplicate the line read with `strdup()` or `strndup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *name[12];

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[100];
        int i, n;
        for (n = 0; n < 12 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), file); n++) {
            name[n] = strndup(line, strcspn(line, "\n"));
        }
        fclose(file);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", name[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            free(name[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`strdup()` and `strndup()` are POSIX standard functions that will be included in the upcoming version of the C Standard.

Here is a simple implementation for systems that lack them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *s) {
    size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *p = malloc(size);
    return p ? memcpy(p, s, size) : p;
}

size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t n) {
    const char *p;
    for (p = s; n --> 0 && *p; p++)
        continue;
    return (size_t)(p - s);
}

char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    size_t len = strnlen(s, n);
    char *p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, len);
        p[len] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

If your system supports the `getline()` function, here is an alternative that will read arbitrary long lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *name[12];

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t size = 0;
        ssize_t len;
        int i, n;
        for (n = 0; n < 12 && (len = getline(&line, &size, file)) > 0; n++) {
            if (line[len - 1] == '\n')
                line[--len] = '\0';
            name[n] = strdup(line);
        }
        free(line);
        fclose(file);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", name[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            free(name[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for using the strdup() and strndup()

Comment: @Deepu: OK, I got carried away.